# Blynk Device (ESP32) disconnects when I turn off my N-Channel MOSFET for my RGBW LED strip

Tags: arduino, mosfet, digital-logic, inductance, esp32

I have a lamp that that consists of a strip of RGBW LED's. I'm using an ESP32 to control the LED's (since they are programmable), and I am controlling the actual LED's through an app called Blynk.

I wanted to add a low side N-Channel MOSFET to my LED's so that when I turn the LED's off through the Blynk app, I would reduce the current draw when the lamp is off since the LED's aren't being powered. I noticed that when I turn the MOSFET off after turning off all of the LED's through the app, the Blynk app says that the MCU is disconnected from Blynk, and I have to hard reset the MCU. I don't understand why this is happening, but my suspicion was the fast turn off with the probably large induction due to the narrow long traces in the LED strips. So I added a 1000uF cap to the Gate-Source of the FET, and the problem still occurred.

One thing I did notice about my MOSFET is that the internal resistance from Gate to source was 25KOhms. I thought that was very strange, but it could be that this MOSFET comes with a internal resistor?

My question here is does anyone have a way to fix this issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: `does anyone have a way to fix this issue?` is a very different question from `what is the fix for this issue?` ... the first question does not ask about the issue

Comment: Your wiring is a bit of a rat’s nest. There is what looks like a regulator without capacitors. We need a schematic to understand your circuit. Putting capacitors across the mosfet gate/source is a bad idea. I’m thinking it might be due to bad wiring layout - what you think are wires are actually resistors and inductors, so the wiring is rather critical. As well, switching the low side of the leds introduces its own problems - you’d be better of with a p-channel mosfet switching the high side.

Comment: @Kartman Is it because when the LED's aren't referenced to GND, they will be floating when the MOSFET is open?

Comment: No, because you get a current path back through the data signal.  Had the leds been powered ftom,say, 12V then there would’ve been smoke, but 5V is not an issue. Nevertheless, you need to be aware that 5V will find its way back via the data signal. I suspect its not that you are switching the low side, but rather an effect from doing that.

Comment: At least provide us with a sketch of your circuit.  What supplies the power? How many leds? Its the little details that matter. You’re probably thinking the circuit is so simple, how could it not work?  It works for everyone else. The reality is not quite that rosy - it is actually quite complex so you need to get a number of things correct. It’s a battle with physics.

Comment: @Kartman I quickly drafted up a schematic of what's on my lamp. For the audio voltage follower circuit, I can't remember exactly what components were used, but it was a voltage follow circuit that took an audio signal from an Alexa and converted it to a 3.3V level compatible signal. Please mind that the FET listed isn't the actual FET on my lamp.

Comment: @jay. You’re still spoon feeding us information! Engineers don’t divine magic from thin air! If I was standing next to you i would be determining all the pieces of the puzzle and then I would have a chance of coming up with a solution.

Comment: @Kartman I gave you 90% of the information that you need... either way, I'm fine with just not using the MOSFET and accepting the slightly higher quiescent current draw. It's not critical to the project since this is powered through the wall with a 5V, 15A Power Supply.